# Creating a view. Replacing a NULL value with an empty string. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I want to create a view from a table where we have a FirstName, LastName and MiddleName column and where the MiddleName might be NULL, plus a salary. I need to replace the MiddleName with and empty string where there's not MiddleName. I'm using SQL Management Studio.
I came up with this code:

```
CREATE VIEW V_EmployeeNameJobTitle AS
SELECT FirstName  + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName AS [Fullname], Salary FROM Employees WHERE MiddleName IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT FirstName  + ' ' + LastName AS [Fullname], Salary FROM Employees WHERE MiddleName IS NULL
```

But this doesn't seem to work as I wanted to, and it's not very pretty. Any other suggestions how I might shorten this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `coalesce(column, '')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ISNULL()` function, where it replaces the NULL value int the value you choose. for ex:

```
CREATE VIEW V_EmployeeNameJobTitle AS
SELECT FirstName  + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddleName, '') + ' ' + LastName AS [Fullname], Salary 
FROM Employees
```

or if you don't want to get 2 spaces when the middle name is null, you can undergo the following:

```
CREATE VIEW V_EmployeeNameJobTitle AS
SELECT (CASE WHEN MiddleName IS NULL THEN FirstName  + ' ' + LastName
             ELSE FirstName  + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName END) AS [Fullname], 
Salary 
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + 
       (case when MiddleName is null then '' else MiddleName + ' ' end) +
       LastName AS [Fullname]
```

Comment: But I want just a single space between FirstName and LastName. If I just use coalesce or isNull won't I have two spaces?

Comment: yes. I just answered that and took your case into consideration

Answer (score 1):

use `IsNull` function

```
 CREATE VIEW V_EmployeeNameJobTitle AS
    SELECT FirstName  + ' ' 
         + MiddleName + ' ' 
         + IsNull(LastName, '') AS [Fullname]
   , Salary 
 FROM Employees
```